# IDEA смена версии maven проектов из IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Как средствами IDE сменить версию всех проектов, дочерних от корневого?
Есть maven команда, которая это делает из консоли `mvn -DnewVersion=1.2.3.4 -versions:set`, но хотелось бы уметь делать это из UI.

Comment: Можно добавить Run configuration для maven и по кнопке запускать maven-release-plugin / maven-versions-plugin. Но вы же не выпекаете релизы каждые 10 минут.

Comment: в intellij idea есть возможность добавлять команды для утилит сборки, в том числе и для maven

Comment: @Nofate, в период тестирования по 4-5 штук в день. У нас около 12 подмодулей. Команда в консоли решает проблему, но её каждую перезагрузку приходится вспоминать/ручками вбивать.

Comment: сделайте bat/sh скрипт и положите в корень проекта )

Comment: Погодите? Вы собираете релизы из IDE?

Comment: @Nofate, в целом да. Просто было интересно, есть ли в idea возможность сделать это автоматически. Пусть вопрос полежит ещё некоторое время, если ответа не будет - удалю.

Comment: @Nofate, релизы - Jenkins, а вот в период тестирования быструю пересборку делаем на локальных машинах.

Comment: @Nofate, к вопросу некоторый интерес всё же возник. Оформите, пожалуйста, в виде ответа ваши суждения. Отрицательный результат - тоже результат. Для сайта не бесполезный вопрос получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Специального инструмента для обновления версии maven-проект в IDEA нет.

Однако вы можете:

- Создать <kbd>Run Configuration</kbd> для maven, которая будет запускать цели плагина maven-release-plugin или maven-versions-plugin. При этом в pom-файле нужно будет предварительно настроить плагин и вспомогательные инструменты для вычисления следующей версии. После этого можно будет выполнять цель по кнопке <kbd>Run</kbd>.
- Запускать те же предварительно настроенные цели maven из боковой панели <kbd>Maven Projects</kbd>
- Написать shell-скрипт, выполняющий нужные действия, и запускать его из дерева проекта командой <kbd>Run</kbd> контекстного меню.

---

PS. Для серьезных целей, вроде выпуска полноценных релизов, не стоит завязываться на функциональность конкретной IDE.